# Copying specific data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, pivot-table, worksheet-function, array-formulas, vba

2 columns on master sheet:

```
col1      col2
Apple     Fruit
Spinach   Veg
Orange    Fruit
Potatoe   Veg   
Pear      Fruit
Bannana   Fruit
Carrot    Veg
Potataoe  Veg
```

Say I wanted to copy all `Fruit` data to a another sheet and all `Veg` data to a 3rd sheet. Is there a way to do this? Does it require a macro or can I somehow do a `VLOOKUP`?

Also I need this to be dynamic, so if a new row is added the corresponding sheets are updated.

Comment: Just auto-filter the columns for `Fruit` -copy the filtered records to sheet 2, then repeat for `Veg`

Comment: Sorry I want this to be dynamic so if a new row is added it will appear on other sheets

Comment: Try 'Record macro', Turn on filter, copy the remaining data to a new sheet, stop recording. With this code you'll be able to get started ;)

Comment: I just quickly typed those in as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this horrible monstrosity of a formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9, SMALL(IF("veg"=$A$2:$A$9, ROW($A$2:$A$9)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$9))+1, ""), ROW(A1)))
```

Enter it as an array formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

[image: HorribleMonstrousityFormula]

I found the formula here:
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/10/25/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/

Which might not be the best version or most elegant version of this formula(it is a common formula task) but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use PivotTables (using Excel 2007) but you will need to refresh each time the source is modified/extended and to keep an eye on Table/Data Range: not stopping short of any additions:

[image: SO12932741 example]

Answer (score 1):

- right click your sheet tab
- View Code
- copy and paste in the code below

whenever column B is changed the code

1. AutoFilters column B for "Fruit", then copies records to sheet 2 columns A:B
2. AutoFilters column B for "Veg", then copies records to sheet 2 columns A:B

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set rng1 = Intersect([B:B], Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set ws1 = Sheets(2)
Set ws2 = Sheets(3)
ws1.[A:B].ClearContents
ws2.[A:B].ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
With ActiveSheet.Range("A:B")
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Fruit"
.Copy ws1.[a1]
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Veg"
.Copy ws2.[a1]
End With
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```